# Socket.IO failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: socket.io

I have a socket.io app hosted in A2Hosting shared hosting and the problem is that it uses only xhr polling because there seems to be an error establishing socket handshake.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.xxxxxxx.com/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=7KqOx4VgE6xd507zAACf' failed: Error 
during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 65533

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
"https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
next();
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Socket is running....'))

// io.set('transports', ['websocket']);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('scan_complete', function (data) {
  io.emit("scan_result", data);
console.log(data);
});
});
```

.htaccess for app.js

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:65533/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:65533/$1 [P,L]
```

client side

```
$(function () {
        var socket = io.connect("https://www.xxxxx.com/");

        socket.on('scan_result', function (msg) {
            $('#content').html(profile);
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
    const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
      serveClient: false,
      // below are engine.IO options
      origins: '*:*',
      transports: ['polling'],  <== this is what solved my problem
      pingInterval: 10000,
      pingTimeout: 5000,
      cookie: false
    });

    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('IO Connected!', socket.id);

      ...

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected!', socket.id);
      });
    });
```

Comment: This has fixed issue for me too. Thanks @lumisi

Comment: FYI I believe by doing this you are in fact disabling web sockets altogether and using the long-polling fallback options, which is considerably more chatty and slower than actual web sockets. The underlying issue should probably be resolved before reverting to just using polling.

Answer (score 0):

try with adding `websocket` in transports

```
var socket = io(
                  'wss://www.xxxxx.com', 
                  { transports: ['websocket'] }
               );


socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.emit('greet', { message: 'I am connected !' });
});

socket.on('scan_result', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```